# Type exists in two libraries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, linq-to-lucene, pagedlist

I'm trying to incorporate [Linq to Lucene](http://www.codeplex.com/linqtolucene) in my Asp.net-mvc project.
As with most web projects, I use the [PagedList](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/07/08/PagedList-Strikes-Back.aspx) type I put in my personal helper library and use it all over the place.
But so did Linq to Lucene...
Since both my library and the L2L library want to add the PagedList type to System.Collections.Generic namespace, I get a conflict message.

Is there a way to resolve this conflict without either having to rewrite my projects or the L2L project?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a bad idea to add types to .NET BCL namespaces since it gives you no benefits whatsoever and causes major troubles in the long run. So the advice might be to move your helper class out of `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: Maybe it is. The funny thing is, this is the exact same class in both libraries. If only there was an official PagedList class in that namespace.